# Are there scenarios where dealloc will get called without viewWillDisappear not being called?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In a controller we have added observer in `viewDidAppear` and it's removed in `viewWillDisappear`.  There is no observer in `init/viewDidLoad`.

In such a case the below line for safety purpose/is it required in `dealloc` method?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Now the question/doubt is are there scenarios where `dealloc` will get called without `viewWillDisappear` not being called? What about when memory warnings are called. What happens in those cases?

Thanks.

Comment: i'm so far happy in my code that viewwilldisappear will be called but i will await the answer. One scenario brought up in discussion was it was suggested the view may not disappear on a memory warning. If this happened would the code run properly in viewdiddisappaer even if called later when the view did disappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*One scenario is:*

1. `VC1` implements the class `HelperVC`, it's delegates and added `HelperVC` as it's subview.
2. Close button on the `HelperVC` calls `closeAll` delegate method, which is implemented in `VC1`.
3. The `closeAll` method in `VC1` sets the `HelperVC` object to `nil`.
4. Now `dealloc` method is called in `HelperVC` instead of `viewWillDisappear`. Because we didn’t remove the `HelperVC` view, we have made `HelperVC` object to `nil`.